# How do I add a condition to react material-ui elements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am building a generic data table using react and material-ui.  My background is c# and java, and early javascript, so I'm having issues w/the syntax in reactjs.

Specifically I have the following code:

```
  <TableRow>
    {formColumns.map((x, i) =>
      ---WRAP THE FOLLOWING IN A CONDITION
      <TableHeaderColumn key={`thc-${i}`}>
        <div
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            alignItems: "center"
          }}
          onClick={() => handleSort(x.name)}
        >
          <span>{x.label}</span>
          {columnToSort === x.name ? (
            sortDirection === "asc" ? (
              <ArrowDownwardIcon fontSize='small' />
            ) : (
                <ArrowUpwardIcon fontSize='small' />
              )
          ) : null}
        </div>
      </TableHeaderColumn>
      ---WRAP THE ABOVE IN A CONDITION
    )}
    <TableHeaderColumn>
      <CheckboxMenu formColumns={formColumns} />
    </TableHeaderColumn>
  </TableRow>
```

The object I'm using for the 'map' is defined as follows:

```
{    id: {
      name: 'id',
      displayColumn: false,
      displayOrder: 1,
    },
    firstName: {
      name: 'firstName',
      label: 'First name*',
      requiredErrorMsg: 'First name is required',
      displayColumn: true,
      displayOrder: 2,
    },
 ...
}
```

I want to wrap the above elements in a condition that looks like this:

```
if (x.displayColumn === true)
{
  ---PUT THE ABOVE CODE BETWEEN THE WRAP COMMENTS HERE
}
else
{
  do nothing
}
```

Seems like an easy thing to do right?  It is in any other language I've used.  But reactjs keeps giving me syntax errors.  Can someone put the above code together correctly and explain to me what I'm doing wrong?  I can't find an answer to this issue anywhere.  Help is much appreciated!

EDITED TO ADD THE FOLLOWING:

When I attempt to do this:

```
  <TableRow>
    {formColumns.map((x, i) =>
    {
      x.displayColumn === true ? (

        <TableHeaderColumn key={`thc-${i}`}>
          <div
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              alignItems: "center"
            }}
            onClick={() => handleSort(x.prop)}
          >
            <span>{x.label}</span>
            {columnToSort === x.name ? (
              sortDirection === "asc" ? (
                <ArrowDownwardIcon fontSize='small' />
              ) : (
                  <ArrowUpwardIcon fontSize='small' />
                )
            ) : null}
          </div>
        </TableHeaderColumn>
      ) : (null) <--ERROR
    }
    )}
    <TableHeaderColumn>
      <CheckboxMenu formColumns={formColumns} />
    </TableHeaderColumn>
  </TableRow>
```

I get this error:

"(ESLint) Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression."

Before someone mentions the (null), I've tried (''), ("") and anything else.  I still get the same error.  The fact is I'd rather use an if statement, since there IS NO ELSE.

Comment: What error does it give or are you using class component or functional component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **ternary operator** to decide the condition.

EX:

```js
<TableRow>
  {formColumns.map((x, i) => (
    x.displayColumn
      ? (
        // PUT THE ABOVE CODE BETWEEN THE WRAP COMMENTS HERE
      )
      : null
    )
  )}
  <TableHeaderColumn>
    <CheckboxMenu formColumns={formColumns} />
  </TableHeaderColumn>
</TableRow>
```

Comment: As you can now see above, I've tried that, and I get the same error.

Comment: Try my updated code?
And if null has problem, you can use a html tag, e.g.  <div />

Comment: I already had tried the ternary operator and explained above I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you change it?  Because I tried your code again and this time it worked!  Thanks!  I was missing the '(' bracket after the => which was causing the error.  Appreciate it!

Comment: This is EXACTLY what the below answer pointed out to you with a precise explanation as to why and this answer was only updated afterwards to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

You were missing the `return` statement

```
<TableRow>
  {formColumns.map((x, i) => {
    // return statement here
    return (
      x.displayColumn === true && (
        <TableHeaderColumn key={`thc-${i}`}>
          <div
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              alignItems: "center",
            }}
            onClick={() => handleSort(x.prop)}
          >
            <span>{x.label}</span>
            {columnToSort === x.name ? (
              sortDirection === "asc" ? (
                <ArrowDownwardIcon fontSize="small" />
              ) : (
                <ArrowUpwardIcon fontSize="small" />
              )
            ) : null}
          </div>
        </TableHeaderColumn>
      )
    );
  })}
  <TableHeaderColumn>
    <CheckboxMenu formColumns={formColumns} />
  </TableHeaderColumn>
</TableRow>;
```

The syntax is as follows

```
<TableRow>
  {formColumns.map((x, i) => {
    return <div>Something</div>
  })}
</TableRow>
```

OR

```
{formColumns.map((x, i) => (
    <div>Something</div>
))}
```

Because `() => { return smthg; }` is equivalent to `() => (smthg)` or `() => smthg` and you have to return something from the `.map` callback to get your JSX evaluated.

Btw. conditional statement in React is just `&&` due to JS specifics.

Because, in the code `flag && someFunc()` someFunc never gets called if `flag` is false. Therefore, doing this way your JSX would never get evaluated and never rendered.

Comment: I only printed a PORTION of my code. I am returning the whole table.  Why would I want to return a tablecolumn and not the table row also?  Your code wouldn't work in any case.  Thanks for trying tho.

Comment: I do appreciate the notice on the && operator.  I've got so many languages in my head that && didn't make sense when i saw the code.  So you're saying if I don't want an else statement I can use:  "x.displayColumn && someFunc()" and put the whole wrapped code in someFunc(i, x)?  Would that work?

Comment: [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator) on conditional rendering with the `&&` operator. This will almost always be safe, but it's best to use the ternary instead, since `0 && /* some JSX */` will actually render `0`

Comment: @aaava actually i have fixed the mistake in your PORTION... `return` statement of the map is not a return statement of the component... This code would work if you would put it all together in correct way...

Comment: Thanks Rostyslav.  The code is working because of the fix from Alvin.  Your answer is duly noted and appreciated.  Still confused why I would have a return statement embedded inside ANOTHER return statement (which I did not display because the code is irrelevant to the problem I was having).  I still have a lot to learn about reactjs after decades of c# and java.

Comment: @aaava Your first `return` is for your component, this one is for the callback function. You are passing a callback function to your `map` higher-order function. You need to return JSX from this function. Leaving React aside for a minute, you need to return _something_ from that callback. The answer you wrongly accepted uses the implicit `return`. How exactly that works is explained in this answer. Instead you can also use an explicit `return`, the result is the same.

Comment: Oh, because it's actually an *anonymous* function inside another function?  Is that what you're saying?  I get it now!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking for another solution, on Material UI 4 this works for me

```
const [activeElement, setactiveElement] = useState(false);


const classes = useStyles({activeElement});//Sent as object

return (
<div onMouseEnter={() => setHoverActive(true)} onMouseLeave={() => setHoverActive(false)} className={classes.card}>

</div>
);

/* Outside the export element */

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    card: {
        backgroundColor: ({activeElement}) => activeElement ? "red": "blue",    
    }

})
```

In this case, when you hover, the background color change... This base on conditions of true/false. A simple example for conditions in Material UI, hope this is use full for someone